# How to move bulma-badge closer to the inside of the element?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have a Bulma badge working on a span inside an anchor tag but the badge is too far from the inner text and thus being cut off by the constraints of the parent element.
How do you move the badge closer to the inner text of the element?

```
<li>
   <a>some text
      <br/>
      <span class="has-badge-rounded" data-badge="42">Some other text</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

but this results in the badge being too far from the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it but I got it to work by overriding the pseudo after css rule attached to Bulma's `[data-badge]`.

```
[data-badge]::after {
    min-width: 1rem;
    min-height: 1rem;
    font-size: .75rem;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

The style that made the badge so far from the contents was `transform: translate(50%, -50%)` which I changed to `transform: translate(0,0)`.

There are some side effects to this. The badge is now applied directly to the tag the data-badge attribute is on and not the parent enclosing tag. (In my example code the badge was above the anchor tag even if it was applied to the span tag. Now it is on the span tag).

I'm answering this just because it worked for me. I'm not completely happy with the solution because I had to override Bulma styling. So feel free to add better answers.